# Are options for command line utilities in powerhsell the same across different languages?

Tags: windows, powershell, language

Are options e.g. `-h` the same across all languages for Windows using powershell?

#### Example

`netstat` is an example of a fairly universal command line utility. I can see that `netstat -h` provides help across both English and French.

Is it true that `netstat -h` will provide help for *all* languages? And if so, does this convention hold true for other programs (not just netstat, which is just an example)

Comment: Are we talking about only built-in programs or any program that might exist.  Third-party language support isn’t entirely up to the developer to provide

Comment: @Ramhound just built in ones, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

This might depend on what you mean by language.

If you mean different natural/Earth languages, I believe that sometimes different-language versions of operating systems will sometimes have some differences.  However, that is rather rare, because the creators of language variants for operating systems know that people want to be able to create compatible automation, and that requires a consistent syntax.  So changing an option may be more prone to cause more pain than benefit.  So you're probably safe, but I wouldn't say 100%.  That's my understanding, broadly.  For more precise specific information, you may need to check the language-specific documentation for a specific command.

If you mean different programming languages, then yes.  It doesn't matter whether you call NetStat from a PowerShell script, or from CMD.exe-based Batch, or having another programming language call an executable file.  The options of NetStat.exe will be the same.

Note that if you're using a command that is internal to the language, that changes things significantly.  For example, PowerShell has an internal command called "`write`".  This command will display a message onto the screen.  CMD does not have such a command, so CMD will just search the PATH variable and find a copy of "`write.exe`", which opens up a copy of WordPad.  (You can also open WordPad from PowerShell by running "`write.exe`" instead of "`write`".)

Of course, PowerShell interprets some characters, like commas, with special meaning, and that special meaning won't necessarily carry over to other command line interpreters.  So a command may potentially need to be adjusted if the typed-up command line contain a feature that has a special meaning in either of the ways being used to run a program.